# Elegant way of specifying either objects or enums as a parameter

Tags: java, enums, polymorphism, superclass

I've made the following code to turn an `ArrayList` (say values `"Cat", "Dog", "Fish"`) into a human-readable string (say `"Cat,Dog,Fish"`), which is a simple task but I want to extend it elegantly. What I've got so far is:

```
public static String makeStringList(Iterable<String> items) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String item : items) {
        sb.append(item);
        sb.append(",");
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

But I have another object which is an `ArrayList` of `Enum` values, say:

```
enum Animal {

    cat("Cat"),
    dog("Dog"),
    fish("Fish");

    String value;

    Animal(String num) {
        value = num;
    }

}
```

And an `ArrayList<Animal>` containing `(Animal.cat, Animal.dog, Animal.fish)`.

What's the best way to extend my `makeStringList` function so that it accepts `ArrayList`s of either `Enum`s or `String`s? I've tried changing the parameter to `Iterable<Object> items` and using `toString()` but apparently my enums don't extend `Object` so there's no `toString()`. I've also tried creating an interface `hasStringRepresentation` with a function `getStringRepresentation`, which works great but won't work for strings.

Is there an elegant way I can extend the makeStringList function to accept either Objects or Enums? The obvious answer is overloading makeStringList but I'd like to limit the question to answers which don't involve overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums do have `toString` method. And you can override it as you wish. You have to use `Iterable<?>` in your function parameter rather than `Iterable<Object>` to allow other types than Object. Its always confusing to use generics in collections.

Comment: That's what I was after, I didn't know Iterable<?> existed - fits the bill perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried changing the parameter to `Iterable<Object>` items and using `toString()` but apparently my enums don't extend `Object` so there's no `toString()`

Enums cannot *not* extend `Object`, because all enums in Java extend [`java.lang.Enum<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), which extends object. All you need to do is overriding the `toString` in your implementation, like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but Netbeans didn't let me use an ArrayList of enums as an Iterable<Object> - I didn't realise I needed Iterable<?>

Comment: @MattLyons I did not realize that you were trying to pass `Iterable<SomeType>` to a parameter that takes `Iterable<Object>`. You cannot do it - with or without enums. You need wildcards for that.

Comment: Yeah, I was using Iterable<Object> to mean an iterable of classes that extend object without realising that it represents a completely different type.